# Redirecting stdout with find -exec and without creating new shell

Tags: linux, unix

I have one script that only writes data to `stdout`. I need to run it for multiple files and generate a different output file for each input file and I was wondering how to use `find -exec` for that. So I basically tried several variants of this (I replaced the script by `cat` just for testability purposes):

```
find * -type f -exec cat "{}" > "{}.stdout" \;
```

but could not make it work since all the data was being written to a file literally named`{}.stdout`.

Eventually, I could make it work with :

```
find * -type f -exec sh -c "cat {} > {}.stdout" \;
```

But while this latest form works well with `cat`, my script requires environment variables loaded through several initialization scripts, thus I end up with:

```
find * -type f -exec sh -c "initscript1; initscript2; ...;  myscript {} > {}.stdout" \;
```

Which seems a waste because I have everything already initialized in my current shell.

Is there a better way of doing this with `find`? Other one-liners are welcome.

Comment: If they are initialized in your original shell, but not set in the subshell, then they are not environment variables.  Write `set -a` at the top of your initscripts.

Comment: Is the last example you give correct, or is the command:`find . -type f -exec sh -c ". initscript1; . initscript2; ...; myscript {} > {}.stdout" \; `  (Instead of simply invoking `initscript1`, are you actually calling `. initscript1`, ie you are sourcing the file with the dot command).

Comment: See also https://superuser.com/questions/1327969/appending-new-lines-to-multiple-files/1327980#1327980

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A simple solution would be to put a wrapper around your script:

```
#!/bin/sh

myscript "$1" > "$1.stdout"
```

Call it `myscript2` and invoke it with find:

```
find . -type f -exec myscript2 {} \;
```

Note that although most implementations of find allow you to do what you have done, technically the behavior of find is unspecified if you use `{}` more than once in the argument list of `-exec`.

Comment: But in `find` manual, somewhere in `-exec` it is said that: _The string '{}' is replaced by the current file name being processed  everywhere it occurs in the arguments to the command, not just in arguments where it is alone, as in some versions of find._ [link](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?find). Still, thanks for the workaround.

Comment: The manual for your particular implementation of `find` state that it works, but the standard reads: `If more than one argument containing only the two characters "{}" is present, the behavior is unspecified.`  It's not a big deal, but is something that can burn you (at which point it suddenly becomes a big deal!)

Comment: A more important disadvantage is that things like `-exec sh -c "myscript {} > {}.stdout" \;` can cause arbitrary code execution in the face of hostile file names. It is more secure to do `-exec sh -c 'myscript "$1" > "$1.stdout"' sh {} \;`.

Comment: Had someone come up with a very similar question today, and I was disappointed to find that I couldn't find anything I really *liked* as a duplicate for it; hence the effort. If this question were in its current state a few hours ago (the `eval` approach not tied with the accepted answer, and the accepted answer not having the now-fixed quoting bug), I probably would have just closed the other as dupe.

Answer (score 24):

You can do it with eval.  It may be ugly, but so is having to make a shell script for this.  Plus, it's all on one line.
For example

```
find -type f -exec bash -c "eval md5sum {}  > {}.sum " \;
```

Comment: The `bash -c` is the beef here, the `eval` isn't actually doing anything useful. But you are not avoiding the shell.

Comment: If you take out the `eval` I'm thinking this should be the accepted answer actually, even though the OP would lilke to avoid a shell. (Putting a script in a separate file creates a shell when running that script anyway.  What the OP is asking isn't really possible.)

Comment: The `eval` is actively dangerous here. If you have a file name that contains `$(rm -rf $HOME)`, this is going to be **very** bad news.

Comment: @tripleee, even without the `eval` this is still dangerous, because you're running your filenames through `bash -c`. *With* the `eval`, you're evaluating each filename through the shell parser twice; without it, you're evaluating it once. The only acceptable number of times data is parsed as code is from a security perspective *zero*.

Comment: So a secure rephrase would be `find -type f -exec bash -c 'for f; do md5sum "$f" >"$f.sum"; done' _ +` but that won't avoid the shell either, of course (and basically duplicates the existing answer by @CharlesDuffy).

Answer (score 4):

If you *export* your environment variables, they'll already be present in the child shell (If you use `bash -c` instead of `sh -c`, and your parent shell is itself bash, then you can also export *functions* in the parent shell and have them usable in the child; see `export -f`).

Moreover, by using `-exec ... {} +`, you can limit the number of shells to the smallest possible number needed to pass all arguments on the command line:

```
set -a # turn on automatic export of all variables
source initscript1
source initscript2

# pass as many filenames as possible to each sh -c, iterating over them directly
find * -name '*.stdout' -prune -o -type f \
  -exec sh -c 'for arg; do myscript "$arg" > "${arg}.stdout"' _ {} +
```

Alternately, you can just perform the execution in your current shell directly:

```
while IFS= read -r -d '' filename; do
  myscript "$filename" >"${filename}.out"
done < <(find * -name '*.stdout' -prune -o -type f -print0)
```

See [UsingFind](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/UsingFind) discussing safely and correctly performing bulk actions through `find`; and [BashFAQ #24](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024) discussing the use of process substitution (the `<(...)` syntax) to ensure that operations are performed in the parent shell.

Comment: Using `_` as $0 to the invoked sh is a bit obfuscating!

Comment: @WilliamPursell, it's a common idiom -- can find links if you like. (`_` is also a conventional unused/placeholder value in some other languages, such as Python, but my understanding is that it was common in shell first).

Comment: I've seen it used in go and perl, but never in this setting.  I tend to ignore it and set $0 to {}, which is probably a much worse practice!