# Adding simple pipped command bash

Tags: bash, git

I'm learning bash scripting and needed some simple help.

Here is what I have thus far:

```
find . -type d -empty -not -path "./.git/*" -exec touch {}/.gitkeep \;
```

So what this does is starts from a root path, finds all directories inside this root path that are empty and do not have a `.git` folder, and then when that operation is successful it runs `-exec touch {}/.gitkeep` to create a file `.gitkeep` inside that empty directory to ensure proper git commits.

What I want now is to `echo` out the current file path for the `gitkeep` file just created.

My first question is:

Should I be piping `|` as so:

```
find . -type d -empty -not -path "./.git/*" -exec touch {}/.gitkeep | outputFilenameDisplayFunction \;
```

Or maybe repeat what `-exec` does as so:

```
find . -type d -empty -not -path "./.git/*" -exec touch {}/.gitkeep - exec outputFilenameDisplayFunction \;
```

Or maybe use `>`

```
find . -type d -empty -not -path "./.git/*" -exec touch {}/.gitkeep > outputFilenameDisplayFunction \;
```

None of these commands has been tested yet. I really am looking for *explanations* so i can be knowledgeable in the future.

Comment: Re: `> outputFilenameDisplayFunction` -- redirections are interpreted *by the shell* before it even starts `find`. Consequently, it's not part of the `-exec` sequence (when you have a shell that honors them in non-head-or-tail position, as bash does); and even if you quoted it, as in `'>outputFilenameDisplayFunction'`, such an idiom is a *shell redirection*; when you have no shell at all (and `-exec` doesn't start a new shell on its own), nothing is there to honor it.

Comment: ...btw, if what you really want is to pipe something to a function -- because `-exec` starts a program directly (with no shell), it can't directly start a shell function (which, by nature, only exists when you *have a shell* in the first place). You *can* run a shell function under `-exec` if you export it with `export -f` and ensure that the child shell is bash, but that's a fair bit of work, and generally not the best approach for the job.

Comment: In general, I'd suggest referring to the practices in [Using Find](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/UsingFind) -- note in particular the use of NUL-delimited streams to pass names from `find` to a bash `while read` list (a technique discussed also in [BashFAQ #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001)).

Comment: BTW, `-exec touch '{}/.gitkeep'` isn't guaranteed to work everywhere -- the POSIX specification for `find` only promises that `{}` is honored when it's a standalone argument on its own, not when it's a substring of another argument, so operating systems with simpler `find` implementations may not behave as you intend here.

Answer (score 1):

As [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6043896/6309), `find` accepts multiple `-exec` portions to the command.

In your case, the second one can call a script, as [in here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15031448/6309):

```
find . -type d -empty -not -path "./.git/*" -exec touch {}/.gitkeep \; -exec myscript {} \;
```

Note the `\;`.

The script would be:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "$1" > "afile"
```

[Charles Duffy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14122/charles-duffy) actually proposes [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49216110/adding-simple-pipped-command-bash/49216289?noredirect=1#comment85436814_49216289) fir the second `-exec`:

```
-exec sh -c 'echo "$1" >>aFile' _ {} \;
```

> avoid the need for an external file storing your script.

Comment: Keeping the `-path './.git/*'` is unfortunate -- that's a quite inefficient construct compared to using `-prune`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I agree. I was simply building on the base command proposed by the OP.

Comment: BTW, I believe there are some whitespace-related typos here right now -- presumably you mean to have a space before the `\;`, and no space between the following `-` and `exec`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Right, fixed.

Comment: LGTM, though personally, I might `-exec sh -c 'echo "$1" >>aFile' _ {} \;` or such and avoid the need for an external file storing your script.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Good point. I missed https://stackoverflow.com/a/25507672/6309 before.

Answer (score 1):

Let's start from your stated requirements:

> So what this does is starts from a root path, finds all directories inside this root path that are empty and do not have a .git folder, and then when that operation is successful it runs -exec touch {}/.gitkeep to create a file .gitkeep inside that empty directory to ensure proper git commits.

If a directory is empty, it "can't have a `.git` folder" in the sense of having a child named `.git` *by definition* -- if it had any subdirectory, it wouldn't be empty. So we can completely ignore that part of your description in prose -- or interpret to refer to what the code *actually appears to be intended to do*, pruning any directory which is *under* `.git`.

Should that be your intent, `-path` is the wrong tool for that job altogether, as it still searches the `.git` tree (and then excludes all the things that it found); instead, use `-prune` to stop `find` from recursing down that path at all:

```
while IFS= read -r -d '' dirname; do
  touch -- "${dirname}/.gitkeep"
  printf '%q\n' "$dirname" # this goes to the logfile, since we open it for the whole loop
done < <(find . -name .git -prune -o -type d -empty -print0) >logFile
```

Why prefer this approach?

- Instead of starting a shell per directory found (as would happen if you used `-exec` to start a shell script or a shell), it keeps your initial/primary shell running, and iterates through the loop once per item found.
- Because it's running code in that shell, you can use shell functions; modify shell variables (as with `(( ++directoriesFound ))` to keep a counter, f/e), or perform redirections scoped to the loop (ie. `>logFile`) to open an output file just once and use if repeatedly within.

Comment: That seems certainly better than using `-path`. +1

Answer (score 1):

On GNU/anything, `find` has `-printf`, which makes doing what you want a straight

```
find -name .git -prune \
  -o -type d -empty -printf %p/.gitkeep\\n -execdir touch {}/.gitkeep \;
```

(note: fixed omitted `{}/`, and  GNU find's `-execdir` doesn't change the behavior here but is safer than `-exec` on systems that may find themselves under attack, the exec'd command is run directly in the location `find` got to rather than causing the executed command to re-walk the path).